# Как нажать на recaptha selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Как нажать на капчy через selenium. есть код который я смог собрать по кускам с всяких разных сайтов но он не работает подскажите что не так?

```
'driver.switch_to.default_content()'
'driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']"))'
'time.sleep(0.1)'
'driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]').click()'
'driver.switch_to.default_content()'
```

Comment: Это весь ваш код или это только часть?

Comment: часть. часть ))

Comment: У меня работает ваша часть как надо, если добавить импорты, экземпляр браузера и открытие сайта

Comment: у меня она не работает 0_0

Comment: Опубликовал в ответе работающий код. Попробуйте скопировать его и запустить

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vaoxg35KfYZf

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код + часть отсутствующего кода:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')  # открываем страницу с рекапчей
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']"))
time.sleep(0.1)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: хм это может быть связано с тем что у меня капчя появляется после нажатия на кнопку?
просто чтобы капча появилась мне нужно нажать активируй и через 0.4милисекунды она появляется

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vaoxg35KfYZf

Comment: Значит, к тому времени, когда выполняется код, у вас еще не появилась капча. Жмите на кнопку активируй, затем задержка и потом уже капча